# Why isn't Jquery date picker icon showing in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

I have the following code in my html page.
The icon exists and the path to the image is valid. 
Every browser seem to display this correctly except IE8 which only shows a rey box.
Does anyone know a way around that?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

 var sDate = new Date(1323637200000);

  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

      minDate: -151,
      maxDate: "-1D",
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      defaultDate: sDate,
      firstDay: 6,
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "/public/images/ico-calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: false,
      onSelect: function(mydate) {
            window.location.href="/reports/"+mydate;
        }
    });
  });
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="datepicker" />
```

Comment: try using ~/public/images/ico-calendar.gif

Comment: This does not change anything. The image uri is correct and other browsers can display the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling I discovered that resetting the maximum width on the icon image allowed the icon to appear correctly. That sounds like a quirk with IE 8.

```
img{
 max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the html to

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/Vfy6V/7/). I have not given a valid image path. You need to check it on your dev system.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue for people, but I solved it with a small jQuery script:

```
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE');
        var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
        //Check if IE
        if (msie > 0 || trident > 0) {
            $("input[type=date]").datepicker();
        }
```

Works like a charm on Chrome and all IE versions.